# Report subscription error and SharePoint 2013 permissions

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

I was getting the error below when trying to set up a subscription for a report in SharePoint (integrated mode). It's a new SharePoint installation set up by a third party and the third party is no longer available to help. I fixed the error by giving the service account sysadmin rights in SQL Server, but is that dangerous? If so, what should I have done?

> An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due
>   to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the
>   database. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException:
>   An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due
>   to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the
>   database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The EXECUTE
>   permission was denied on the object 'xp_sqlagent_notify', database
>   'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

Comment: In SSRS Configuration there is a service account configuration. In 2012 you can normally get away with running this account as the "ReportServer" account that was created during installation. Do you know if your SSRS database is on the same server as SSRS?

Comment: I see a SharePoint_Reporting_Service database in the same instance that has all the other SharePoint databases. I don't see any SQL logins like ReportServer.

Comment: This link on [Create RSExecRole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/create-the-rsexecrole?view=sql-server-2017) helped me with this issue. It lists a bunch of items RSExec needs Execute permissions for.